# How to read the disordered text data?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to read a text data line by line into memory and write it to the file with different format. The data looks something like this:

```
   15LI     aLI   15   9.34   5.31   5.53
   15LI     aLI   15   9.51   4.55   5.54
   15LI     aLI   15   9.45   4.30   5.47
   15LI     aLI   15  10.29   3.77   5.91
   15LI     aLI   15 -97.89 -21.55   5.47
   15LI     aLI   15 -97.85 -21.69   5.88
   15LI     aLI   15 -96.61 -21.03   5.24
   15LI     aLI   15-103.25  -9.02   5.24
   15LI     aLI   15-102.55  -9.73   5.07
   15LI     aLI   15-102.54  -9.70   5.64
   15LI     aLI   15-102.40  -9.68   5.54
```

As you can see the space between columns 3 and 4 vanishes as the number increases. I'm using the **numpy.genfromtxt** to read the data, but it is unable to read the data after sixth line and throws the following error:

```
 ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #7 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
    Line #8 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
    Line #9 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
    Line #10 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
```

Are there any ways in python to create space between the columns or read them without the space? Here is my small code:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np

#define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S4'), ('col2', 'S4'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])

# Next, create an empty .h5 file with the dtype
with h5py.File('pep.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    ds= hdf.create_dataset('dataset1', dtype=gro_dt, shape=(20,), maxshape=(None,)) 

    # Next read line 1 of .gro file
    f = open('testing.dat', 'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    ds.attrs["Source"]=data[0]
    f.close()

    # loop to read rows from 2 until end
    skip, incr, row0 = 0, 20, 0 
    read_gro = True
    while read_gro:
        arr = np.genfromtxt('testing.dat', skip_header=skip, max_rows=incr, dtype=gro_dt)
        rows = arr.shape[0]
        if rows == 0:
            read_gro = False 
        else:    
            if row0+rows > ds.shape[0] :
                ds.resize((row0+rows,))
            ds[row0:row0+rows] = arr
            skip += rows
            row0 += rows
```

Comment: Struggling with same issue!!

Comment: Is first 3 column will remain same for rest of the file? If possible also share the `pep.h5` file

Comment: yes they remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually parse the data and then dump it in to whatever format you need. This answer works off of the assumption that you state, "the first 3 columns remain the same."

```
import pandas as pd

def gen_lines(filename):
    wanted = 6
    with open(filename, "r") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) < wanted:
                first = parts[:2]
                final = parts[3:]
                middle = parts[2].split("-")
                middle[-1] = "-" + middle[-1]
                yield first + middle + final
            else:
                yield parts

lines = gen_lines("foo.txt")
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)

print(df)
       0    1   2        3       4     5
0   15LI  aLI  15     9.34    5.31  5.53
1   15LI  aLI  15     9.51    4.55  5.54
2   15LI  aLI  15     9.45    4.30  5.47
3   15LI  aLI  15    10.29    3.77  5.91
4   15LI  aLI  15   -97.89  -21.55  5.47
5   15LI  aLI  15   -97.85  -21.69  5.88
6   15LI  aLI  15   -96.61  -21.03  5.24
7   15LI  aLI  15  -103.25   -9.02  5.24
8   15LI  aLI  15  -102.55   -9.73  5.07
9   15LI  aLI  15  -102.54   -9.70  5.64
10  15LI  aLI  15  -102.40   -9.68  5.54
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pd.read_fwf`. Adjust the widths as necessary for your file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf("test.txt", widths=[7, 8, 5, 7, 7, 7])
>>> df
       0    1   2       3      4     5
0   15LI  aLI  15    9.34   5.31  5.53
1   15LI  aLI  15    9.51   4.55  5.54
2   15LI  aLI  15    9.45   4.30  5.47
3   15LI  aLI  15   10.29   3.77  5.91
4   15LI  aLI  15  -97.89 -21.55  5.47
5   15LI  aLI  15  -97.85 -21.69  5.88
6   15LI  aLI  15  -96.61 -21.03  5.24
7   15LI  aLI  15 -103.25  -9.02  5.24
8   15LI  aLI  15 -102.55  -9.73  5.07
9   15LI  aLI  15 -102.54  -9.70  5.64
10  15LI  aLI  15 -102.40  -9.68  5.54

#as a numpy array
array = pd.read_fwf("test.txt", widths=[7, 8, 5, 7, 7, 7]).values
>>> array
array([['15LI', 'aLI', 15, 9.34, 5.31, 5.53],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, 9.51, 4.55, 5.54],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, 9.45, 4.3, 5.47],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, 10.29, 3.77, 5.91],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -97.89, -21.55, 5.47],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -97.85, -21.69, 5.88],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -96.61, -21.03, 5.24],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -103.25, -9.02, 5.24],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -102.55, -9.73, 5.07],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -102.54, -9.7, 5.64],
       ['15LI', 'aLI', 15, -102.4, -9.68, 5.54]], dtype=object)
```